# ng-repeat by month with AngularJS and MomentJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have a an array with objects looking like this:

```
{
"date":"11/11/2014",
"time":"17.20.37",
"car":"396",
"driver":"Jenny",
"from":"Old Office",
"destination":"Log WH",
"pax":"3","comment":"",
"commenttime":"",
"arrival":"17.20.48",
"inserted":true,
"cancelled":"",
"duration":"00:00:11"
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to automatically list the items by month, like the following:

```
-November 2014

   ng-repeat with records from 11-14

-October 2014

   ng-repeat with records from 10-14
```

I know this involves going through the array and getting together all items that have a common property (the same month and year).

I'm already doing that with the car code, listing the different unique car codes like so:

```
var carsDict = {};

angular.forEach($scope.recordlist, function(record) {
  carsDict[record.car] = carsDict[record.car] || [];
  carsDict[record.car].push(record);
});

$scope.carstats = carsDict;
```

This piece of code creates an array of objects for every unique car code (`record.car`).

I could do the same with the `record.date` property (which is a moment() object) but it would group together all objects that have the same exact date in common, not the same month and year.

Any idea about how to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggf9xakf/5/) of where I got until now. In the example I list the car codes, trips (every object in the array is a trip) and time in the road (sum of all record.duration) for each car.

Right now it makes the calculation and shows the results for all the objects of the `recordlist`, but the next step is to do the same, but by list it automatically by month.

Comment: What I've you done in the view (HTML) ?

Comment: I suggest you to reconstruct an array of object containing only months/year. Then loop into that array and filter your current data to fill each month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each records list you need to create a year-month dictionary (2014-11):

```
var monthsDict = {};

angular.forEach(records, function(record) {
  var month = moment(record.date).format('YYYY-MM');
  monthsDict[month] = monthsDict[month] || [];
  monthsDict[month].push(record);
});
```

You can sort it if you need like so:

```
var sortDates = function(a,b) { return moment(a.date) - moment(b.date); };

angular.forEach(monthsDict, function(month) {
  month.sort(sortDates);
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Is it possible to actually create dict. from the items inside monthsDict?
Something like:

    `angular.forEach(monthDict, function(record) {`

       `carsDict[record.car] = carsDict[record.car] || [];
        carsDict[record.car].push(record);
        driversDict[record.driver] = driversDict[record.driver] || [];
        driversDict[record.driver].push(record);`
     `});`